# how to use dynamic import library from google in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps

i tried to add Dynamic import library from google maps in `index.html` like this

```
<script>
  (g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})({
    key: "YOUR_API_KEY",
    v: "weekly",
    // Use the 'v' parameter to indicate the version to use (weekly, beta, alpha, etc.).
    // Add other bootstrap parameters as needed, using camel case.
  });
</script>
```

and in `src/pages/GoogleMaps.vue`

```
export default {
  name: 'GoogleMapsImplementation',
  async created() {
    await this.initMap();
  },
  methods: {
    async initMap() {
      const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary('maps');

      this.map = new Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 8,
      });
    },
  },
};
```

then I got `"ReferenceError: google is not defined"`

is it not possible to use global var in vue js methods from index.html ??
Does anyone have some issue like this?

Answer (score 0):

The official [google maps npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js) does not support browser environment, **Node.js applications is the only supported environment for this library**. For further informationm, please checkout this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46896362/how-to-install-google-maps-through-npm) question

So, in any case you want to use google maps in browser environment, you have to use **Unofficial packages** to do that.

I highly recommend [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader) with millions of weekly download.